# Unable to load Collada exported from three.js

Tags: three.js, collada, sketchup

I have been trying to export a model made in three.js as collada into sketchup. It seems like exported collada from three is corrupted and is not loading in sketchup/blender. I also went through official example for collada-exporter in three.js docs, still the problem is not solved. How to resolve this issue? Is there any way to repair collada file and then import it in other software (preferably sketchup).

Thanks!

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=collada#misc_exporter_collada

Comment: When I export the teapot from the example, I can load it without problems at Sketchfab and preview it with Quicklook 3D. Does Sketchub also allow `glTF` imports? If so, use `THREE.GLTFExporter` instead.

Comment: are you exporting the wireframe version of the teapot? if so try exporting with glossy shading option.

Comment: The glossy shading option works fine. When exporting the wireframe version, the resulting `DAE` file can be loaded at Sketchfab however the wireframe is lost (so the model is solid).

Comment: EDIT: for me sketchup is crashing for all the for all shading options, except for wireframe, dont know what is causing the crash. can you please tell the version of sketchup you are using to import collada files? and on which OS?

Comment: I've not tested with Sketchup but with [Sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com)^^. I suggest you file a bug at Sketchup. The Collada files seems valid to me.